# Can I change the index pattern of a visualization in Kibana?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have created a full set of visualizations.Due to some reason I have to deleted that index in elastic. We need to create a new pattern of index. Problem is that after deleting index visualizations will not work . I will have to recreate it one by one painfully.
Is there a way that I can go and edit visualization and just modify index pattern rather creating a new visualization itself.

Answer (score 23):

Go to `Settings`->`Objects`->`Visualizations` and you can edit the definition manually.

Comment: Amazing  Alain .You got expertise to be proud of.

Comment: I've just tested it and the exact same solution seems to work for searches. By the way, you can get your index pattern code from the URL when you are at Management>Index Patterns. The code is the part that comes after https://.../.../.../.../kibana/indices/{HERE_GOES_THE_CODE}

Comment: For Kibana Version: 6.4.2 Navigation is Management > Saved Objects then search for your object.

Comment: Where is the Settings option? I'm using Kibana 7.10.0

Comment: Kibana 7.11.2: Stack Management > Kibana: Saved Objects > Actions: Inspect

Answer (score 6):

*First let's discuss* **WHY** this whole issue is coming.

My environment is: **Kibana v7.0.1** / **7+**

This issue comes if you have created an *Index-Pattern* (using Kibana's GUI / website) instead of creating the same using ELK/Kibana's **Saved Objects** REST-API (ex: using Curl or some Python/Groovy script to call the rest api to create an index-pattern).

When you create an **Index-Pattern** using GUI, you basically

**STEP 1**: just type the name of the index and

**STEP 2:** *a very important field* called: **Time Filter Field Name** (aka "*timeFieldName*" which is used for generating / treating **"EVENTS"** available in indexed data (data is present in a ***matching*** Elasticsearch Index that you get for the pattern you provide in *STEP 1*).

**Ex:** If you create an index-pattern in Kibana by the name: **jira-*** then, it'll look for any available indexes in Elasticsearch where index starts with *jira-* (ex: *jira-dev, jira-prod,.. jira-demo*,..etc)

[image]

Anyways, once this is done via GUI, what we don't or are NOT allowed to specify is INDEX-PATTERN's **ID** value (which is **very important and directly related** to the **ISSUE** here).

When index-pattern is created in Kibana's GUI, ELK process assigns a **random/unique** Index-Pattern **ID** value to the newly created Index-Pattern that you created.

1. You can see that Index-Pattern's ID if you hover over you mouse on the index-pattern in GUI (under: Gear button > Index-Patterns > hover over an index-pattern and see in the status bar URL for ID value the last value after a `/` slash).

**Next**, you create the Visualization (where you tie what index-pattern you want to use) and later add visualizations to dashboards.

Cool: let's say, one day you accidentally delete this index-pattern (i.e. *jira-** in Kibana) --or the index itself (Elasticsearch index i.e *jira-dev*).

In **case**: where you ended up deleting just the index (in Elasticsearch), you can re-create the index again with the same index **name** *jira* and the existing *index-pattern* i.e. **jira-*** will pick the newly created Elasticsearch index easily (you may have to click on the refresh button).

In **case**: you were lucky enough to delete the index-pattern (**jira-*** here), then that **magical/hidden/auto-generated long alpha-numeric** Index **ID** that was generated for free (will be deleted) and your visualization and dashboards (using such visualization) barf and your managers will definitely cry for some urgent help!

**One work-around solution is**: recreate the index-pattern *jira-**. Find it's ID (you can use Saved Object's GET rest api on index-pattern to get this value) and then click on `Gear button > under Saved Objects > search your visulization`  and see `ID` value in **references** JSON section and change the OLD alpha-numeric value (of the deleted *jira-** index with the new **ID** value of the newly created index-pattern. This will get you going.

**Now, HOW** to **AVOID** all this **MESS**: If you had created your **index-pattern** using Kibana's Saved Objects *REST API* **then**, it **ALLOWS** you to provide the **ID** value (the last value in the rest-api URL after `/`) **which is HUMAN readable string name** and what this **means is**: *if you ever delete/lose the index-pattern* and **if re-create the same index-pattern** then you'll **NEVER EVER** have to worry about these long *auto-generated alpha-numeric* **ID** values that Kibana GUI creates behind the scene and you don't have to change anything in your Visualizations/Dashbaords.

**Ex:** How to create an index-pattern in Kibana (v7.0.1 / 7+) is:

```
(venvPython375) [gigauser@ip-11.22.33.44 myfolder]$ curl -X POST -u $user:$pass -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "kbn-xsrf:true"  "${KIBANA_URL}/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/jira-index" -d '{ "attributes": { "title":"jira-*","timeFieldName":"sprint_start_date"}}'  -w "\n"|jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   327  100   250  100    77    543    167 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   543
{
  "type": "index-pattern",
  "id": "jira-index",
  "attributes": {
    "title": "jira-*",
    "timeFieldName": "start_of_work"
  },
  "references": [],
  "migrationVersion": {
    "index-pattern": "6.5.0"
  },
  "updated_at": "2020-02-25T22:56:44.531Z",
  "version": "Wzg5NCwxNV0="
}
```

NOTICE: `"id": "jira-index",` this is important and is HUMAN READABLE (**ID**) value for the index you just created.

You basically created a index-pattern by the name (see TITLE value) i.e. **jira-*** and it's **ID** value is: jira-index (HUMAN readable), this ID value is easier to maintain, remember and to be used in `GET` operations! (Now you don't have to remember the long dynamically generated ID that you got when you were creating the index-pattern in Kibana's GUI/web-page).

To see an Index-Pattern, now you can use the HUMAN readable ID value to see it, rather than some long alpha-numeric ID.

```
curl -X GET "${KIBANA_URL}/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/jira-index" | jq
```

Now, if you create a new visualization and use "jira-*" as index-pattern and if you ever delete the index-pattern, then recreating the same jira-* pattern with **title/name** as "**jira-***" will always keep "jira-index" as it's **ID** (and because your visualization was using the HUMAN readable ID and which got created after an accidental delete / recreated if you wanted to), you'll NEVER lose your data or EVER have to delete or recreate your Visualizations/Dashboards!, therefore it's like *Merry X-mas baeby!!*

For information about Index-Patterns (how to get human readable Index-Pattern ID), see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60404691/1499296

Answer (score 1):

As of Kibana 4.3.1, for some visualizations, you'll have to go to *Settings->Objects->searches*.