# elk kibana cannot create index pattern

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I hava a ELK running, which is pretty ok. But today, I got an exception when trying to create new index pattern.

To solve this issue, I have deleted .kibana index, and .monitoring-kibana-6-xxx indexices.

I also tried to create index pattern by command line ([Create index-patterns from console with Kibana 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410250/create-index-patterns-from-console-with-kibana-6-0)). But I could not set the default index pattern. So I still need to create or set index from UI.

```
Error: 413 Response
    at http://staging.alct56.club/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=16070:231:21272
    at processQueue (http://staging.alct56.club/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=16070:39:9912)
    at http://staging.alct56.club/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=16070:39:10805
    at Scope.$digest (http://staging.alct56.club/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=16070:39:21741)
    at Scope.$apply (http://staging.alct56.club/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=16070:39:24520)
    at done (http://staging.alct56.club/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=16070:38:9495)
    at completeRequest (http://staging.alct56.club/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=16070:38:13952)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (http://staging.alct56.club/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=16070:38:14690)
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I found this is blocked by our company http policy. But I still cannot understand why the "response body is too big" causes index pattern cannot be created.