# Can I change the index pattern for a visualization in OpenSearch

Tags: kibana, opensearch

OpenSearch is a fork of ElasticSearch, which includes things like Kibana built in.  According to this question [Can I change the index pattern of a visualization in Kibana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427511/can-i-change-the-index-pattern-of-a-visualization-in-kibana) in Kibana it was possible using some clever backend to change the index pattern used by a visualization.  AFAICT, this technique no longer works in current OpenSearch builds.

Does anybody know if this is possible without rebuilding the visualizations?